# How to use options of the command \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics

I must insert an image in a page with geometry specified in the MWE, and with the following dimensions: The distance to the top margin must be 8.5cm, the distance to the right must be 6cm, and the dimensions of the image must be 7cm for the height, and 5cm for the width. I do this simply with the command `\includegraphics[height=7cm,width=5cm]` of the package `graphicx`, but the image produced hasn't the suited dimensions. Why and how can I do the job ? Thanks

Here's the `.tex` file used:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\hrule
\vspace*{8.5cm}\hspace*{6cm}
\includegraphics[height=7cm,width=5cm]{tug2018}

\end{document}
```

and the `.pdf` file produced, using `xelatex`:

[image]

Comment: Maybe check the real bounding box of  the image, adding an `\fbox` around the \ncludegraphics.

Comment: @Bernard I do this and the box is about 1mm around the image. The dimensions are not those given, 7cm and 5cm

Comment: Quite strange… What kind of image is it?

Comment: tug2018.jpeg from the net

Comment: Excuse me but the original image, where I have a real problem is a PostScript image... Is the problem coming from the format of the image ?

Comment: the extra space shown by `\fbox` is added by `\fbox` (`\fboxsep`)  the options you show will be the final size of the image but (as your image shows) it is usually a bad idea to use both height and width as that distorts the image. If you are using pdflatex or xetex then it is best to convert your postscript to pdf first, as they can not natively include ps, although the graphics package will try to convert automatically if needed.

Comment: Thank you for both. I will try to transform the eps image,  I will try with the option `keepaspectratio` too, see the result and choose the better. Many thanks for your disponibility